# pointwise convergence almost everywhere in two variables

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let Let $f_n : X\times Y\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of measurable functions which converge almost everywhere to $f$, with respect to the measure $\mu\otimes\nu$. Is it true that for almost every $x\in X$, $f_{n}(x,y)$ converge to $f(x,y)$ for almost every $y\in Y$?

Answer (score 1):

You have to precise the measures considered whenever you write « almost every ». If we assume that $f_n \to f$ $(\mu \otimes \nu)$- everywhere, then for $\mu$-almost every $x$, we have $f_n(x,\cdot) \to f(x,\cdot)$ $\nu$-everywhere on $Y$. This follows from the equality
$$0 = (\mu \otimes \nu) \{(x,y) \in X \times Y : f_n(x,y) \not\to f(x,y)\} = \int_X \nu\{y \in Y : f_n(x,y) \not\to f(x,y)\} d\mu(x).$$

Comment: Thank u, with "$\mu\otimes\mu$ everywhere", u mean almost everywhere with respect to the $\mu\otimes\nu$?

Comment: @user44155 Yes, indeed.